# DropDown not working with Bokeh

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, bokeh

I have a script to plot the prices of some share that the user wants to look at : he can choose the shares via a Dropdown button and Bokeh will draw the curve accordingly.
(I am working in jupyter notebook) :

```
from bokeh.io import output_notebook, show
from bokeh.plotting import figure
output_notebook()
```

my code is the following :

```
from bokeh.models import  Callback, ColumnDataSource, Select,CustomJS
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, gridplot
from bokeh.models.widgets.layouts import VBox
import pandas as pd

shares = ['AAPL', 'MSFT', 'IBM', 'All']

AAPL = pd.read_csv("http://ichart.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=AAPL&a=0&b=1&c=2000&d=0&e=1&f=2015",parse_dates=['Date'])
MSFT = pd.read_csv("http://ichart.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=MSFT&a=0&b=1&c=2000&d=0&e=1&f=2015",parse_dates=['Date'])
IBM = pd.read_csv("http://ichart.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=IBM&a=0&b=1&c=2000&d=0&e=1&f=2015",parse_dates=['Date'])

max_price = max(AAPL['Adj Close'].max(), MSFT['Adj Close'].max(), IBM['Adj Close'].max()) + 10
min_date = min(AAPL['Date'].min(), MSFT['Date'].min(), IBM['Date'].min())
max_date = max(AAPL['Date'].max(), MSFT['Date'].max(), IBM['Date'].max())

myplot = figure(title="Share price", x_axis_type="datetime", x_range=[min_date,max_date],y_range=[0,max_price],
        background_fill='#FFF5EE', plot_width=900, plot_height = 400, outline_line_color= None)

source_AAPL = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=AAPL['Date'], y = AAPL['Adj Close'], ytemp = AAPL['Adj Close']))
source_MSFT = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=MSFT['Date'], y = MSFT['Adj Close'], ytemp = MSFT['Adj Close']))
source_IBM  = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=IBM['Date'],  y = IBM['Adj Close'],  ytemp = IBM['Adj Close']))

myplot.line(x ='x', y ='y', color='#A6CEE3', source = source_AAPL, name='AAPL')
myplot.line(x ='x', y ='y', color='#33A02C', source = source_MSFT, name='IBM')
myplot.line(x ='x', y ='y', color='#FB9A99', source = source_IBM, name='MSFT') 


Callback_Shares = CustomJS(args={'source_AAPL': source_AAPL,'source_MSFT': source_MSFT,'source_IBM': source_IBM}, code="""
    var f = cb_obj.get('value');
    var data_AAPL = source_AAPL.get('data');
    var data_MSFT = source_MSFT.get('data');     
    var data_IBM = source_IBM.get('data');
    if (f == 'AAPL') {
        data_MSFT['y'] = [0 for i in range(len(data_MSFT['x']))];
        data_IBM['y'] = [0 for i in range(len(data_IBM['x']))];
        data_AAPL['y'] = data_AAPL['ytemp'] ;
        source_AAPL.trigger('change');
        source_MSFT.trigger('change');
        source_IBM.trigger('change');
        }
    if (f == 'MSFT') {
        data_AAPL['y'] = [0 for i in range(len(data_AAPL['x']))];
        data_IBM['y'] = [0 for i in range(len(data_IBM['x']))];
        data_MSFT['y'] = data_MSFT['ytemp'] ;
        source_AAPL.trigger('change');
        source_MSFT.trigger('change');
        source_IBM.trigger('change');
        }
    if (f == 'IBM') {
        data_AAPL['y'] = [0 for i in range(len(data_AAPL['x']))];
        data_MSFT['y'] = [0 for i in range(len(data_MSFT['x']))];
        data_IBM['y'] = data_IBM['ytemp'] ;
        source_AAPL.trigger('change');
        source_MSFT.trigger('change');
        source_IBM.trigger('change');
        }
    if (f == 'All') {
        data_AAPL['y'] = data_AAPL['ytemp'];
        data_MSFT['y'] = data_MSFT['ytemp'];
        data_IBM['y'] = data_IBM['ytemp'];
        source_AAPL.trigger('change');
        source_MSFT.trigger('change');
        source_IBM.trigger('change');
        }"""
)

dropdown = Select(title="Shares:", value=shares[3], options=shares, callback = Callback_Shares)

myfigure =  VBox(dropdown, gridplot([[myplot]]))
show(myfigure)
```

My problem is the figure always shows the 3 curves and does not take into account the choice of the DropDown...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The other answer is unfortunately not an optimal one. As a project maintainer I feel obligated to show the project in the best light. Here is a much simpler complete example that functions the same and works with Bokeh `0.12.4`:

```
from bokeh.models import CustomJS, ColumnDataSource, Select
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show
from bokeh.layouts import column
import pandas as pd

url = "http://ichart.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=%s&a=0&b=1&c=2000&d=0&e=1&f=2015"

AAPL = pd.read_csv(url % "AAPL", parse_dates=['Date'])
MSFT = pd.read_csv(url % "MSFT", parse_dates=['Date'])
IBM  = pd.read_csv(url % "IBM",  parse_dates=['Date'])

max_price = max(AAPL['Close'].max(), MSFT['Close'].max(), IBM['Close'].max())

source = ColumnDataSource({
    'xAAPL' : AAPL['Date'], 'yAAPL' : AAPL['Close'], 'yAAPLp' : AAPL['Close'],
    'xMSFT' : MSFT['Date'], 'yMSFT' : MSFT['Close'], 'yMSFTp' : MSFT['Close'],
    'xIBM'  :  IBM['Date'], 'yIBM'  :  IBM['Close'], 'yIBMp'  :  IBM['Close']
})

p = figure(width=500, height=250, x_axis_type="datetime", y_range=[0, max_price+10])

r_aapl = p.line('xAAPL', 'yAAPL', source=source, color='navy',  alpha=0.5)
r_msft = p.line('xMSFT', 'yMSFT', source=source, color='red',   alpha=0.5)
r_ibm  = p.line('xIBM',  'yIBM',  source=source, color='green', alpha=0.5)

callback = CustomJS(args=dict(r_aapl=r_aapl, r_msft=r_msft, r_ibm=r_ibm), code="""
    f = cb_obj.value;
    r_aapl.visible = false;
    r_msft.visible = false;
    r_ibm.visible = false;
    if      (f == "AAPL") { r_aapl.visible = true; }
    else if (f == "MSFT") { r_msft.visible = true; }
    else if (f == "IBM")  { r_ibm.visible = true; }
    else {
        r_aapl.visible = true;
        r_msft.visible = true;
        r_ibm.visible = true;
    }
""")

shares = ['AAPL', 'MSFT', 'IBM', 'All']
multi_select = Select(title="Select Shares:", value=shares[3], options=shares, callback=callback)

output_file("datetime.html")

show(column(multi_select, p))
```

[image]

[image]

I should also add, "interactive legends" that allow glyphs to be hidden or muted by clicking on the legend, will be added as as standard feature in `0.12.5`.

Comment: This solution does not work for me, I have the same problem : I always see the 3 curves. I am working into Jupyter notebook and my Bokeh version is 0.12.0

Comment: As I mentioned this is a solution for `0.12.4` (probably would work for a version or two earlier too) You never previously stated the version you were using. New features and capabilities are being added consistently, and `0.12.0` is a year old. If you need an answer specific to a particular version (i.e. you are running a year-old version of a fast-moving project), that is *important information* to provide to people trying to help you.

Comment: indeed I should have mentioned it earlier! I have updated bokeh to have 0.12.4 but now I don't see the graphs, I have only the dropdown menu. I use python 2.7 and pandas 0.18.1. (I also have future 0.16.0)

Comment: I just tried with python `2.7`, pandas `0.18` and `0.19` and bokeh `0.12.4` (I'm not sure what `future` is) and it worked as expected. It is possible you have some intermittent network issue and the returned data is empty? If not, perhaps open a bug report on the GH issue tracker, SO is not a good venue for debugging.

Comment: You might also consider an alternative approach using HoloViews to build the Bokeh plot that avoids the need for custom JavaScript; see an example at https://anaconda.org/jbednar/stock_dashboard/notebook .  That example requires bokeh 0.12.4 plus the github master version of HoloViews, or the  HoloViews 1.7 release when it comes out.

Comment: Bokeh was still 0.12.0 into Jupyter. After I changed that it works perfectly fine!

Answer (score 0):

Rather than updating actual data sources, there are much easier ways to control visibility. You can set a glyph's alpha to zero, or color to `None`, or probably most directly, set its renderer's `visible` property to `False` as seen in [this example](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/examples/plotting/file/line_on_off.py). The relevant part of that example, simplified some, is this code:

```
r0 = p.line(x, y0, color="red")
r1 = p.line(x, y1, color="green")
r2 = p.line(x, y2, color="blue")

checkbox = CheckboxGroup(labels=["Line 0", "Line 1", "Line 2"],
                         active=[0, 1, 2], width=100)

checkbox.callback = CustomJS.from_coffeescript(
    args=dict(r0=r0, r1=r1, r2=r2, checkbox=checkbox), 
    code="""
r0.visible = 0 in checkbox.active;
r1.visible = 1 in checkbox.active;
r2.visible = 2 in checkbox.active;
""")
```

Comment: setting the graph option to p1.visible = False does not work

Comment: Are you saying the complete linked example does not work for you? Also not sure what `p1` is or if it is the correct intended thing, it's not in your original code.

Comment: the example does not work : first I had to change "CustomJS.from_coffeescript" for "CustomJS" (AttributeError: type object 'CustomJS' has no attribute 'from_coffeescript') then when I click on the boxes nothing happend

Comment: You have an older version of Bokeh, then. If you had specified what version you are running, I would have made sure to link to one appropriate for your situation. Absent that information, I just linked to the newest available. As  a gentle suggestion, more information will help others help you with better answers.

Answer (score 0):

I found the following solution after quite some work :

```
from bokeh.models import CustomJS, ColumnDataSource, Select
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show
from bokeh.models.layouts import VBox
import pandas as pd

AAPL = pd.read_csv("http://ichart.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=AAPL&a=0&b=1&c=2000&d=0&e=1&f=2015",parse_dates=['Date'])
MSFT = pd.read_csv("http://ichart.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=MSFT&a=0&b=1&c=2000&d=0&e=1&f=2015",parse_dates=['Date'])
IBM = pd.read_csv("http://ichart.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=IBM&a=0&b=1&c=2000&d=0&e=1&f=2015",parse_dates=['Date'])

max_price = max(AAPL['Close'].max(), MSFT['Close'].max(), IBM['Close'].max()) + 10
min_date = min(AAPL['Date'].min(), MSFT['Date'].min(), IBM['Date'].min())
max_date = max(AAPL['Date'].max(), MSFT['Date'].max(), IBM['Date'].max())

output_file("datetime.html")
source = ColumnDataSource({'xAAPL': AAPL['Date'], 'xMSFT': MSFT['Date'], 'xIBM': IBM['Date'], 
                       'yAAPL': AAPL['Close'], 'yAAPLp': AAPL['Close'], \
                       'yMSFT': MSFT['Close'], 'yMSFTp': MSFT['Close'], \
                       'yIBM': IBM['Close'],   'yIBMp': IBM['Close'] })

p = figure(width=500, height=250, x_axis_type="datetime", x_range=[min_date,max_date],y_range=[0,max_price])

p.line('xAAPL', 'yAAPL', source=source, color='navy', alpha=0.5)
p.line('xMSFT', 'yMSFT', source=source, color='red', alpha=0.5)
p.line('xIBM',  'yIBM',  source=source, color='green', alpha=0.5)

callback = CustomJS(args=dict(source=source), code="""
    var data = source.get('data');
    var f = cb_obj.get('value')
    yAAPL = data['yAAPL']
    yMSFT = data['yMSFT']
    yIBM  = data['yIBM']
    yAAPLp = data['yAAPLp']
    yMSFTp = data['yMSFTp']
    yIBMp  = data['yIBMp']
    if (f == "AAPL") {
        for (i = 0; i < yAAPL.length; i++) {yAAPL[i] = yAAPLp[i]}            
        for (i = 0; i < yMSFT.length; i++) {yMSFT[i] = 'nan'}
        for (i = 0; i < yIBM.length; i++)  {yIBM[i] = 'nan'}
    } 
    else if (f == "MSFT") {
        for (i = 0; i < yAAPL.length; i++) {yAAPL[i] = 'nan'}            
        for (i = 0; i < yMSFT.length; i++) {yMSFT[i] = yMSFTp[i]}
        for (i = 0; i < yIBM.length; i++)  {yIBM[i] = 'nan'}
    } 
    else if (f == "IBM") {
        for (i = 0; i < yAAPL.length; i++) {yAAPL[i] = 'nan'}            
        for (i = 0; i < yMSFT.length; i++) {yMSFT[i] = 'nan'}
        for (i = 0; i < yIBM.length; i++)  {yIBM[i] = yIBMp[i]}
    }
    else {
        for (i = 0; i < yAAPL.length; i++) {yAAPL[i] = yAAPLp[i]}            
        for (i = 0; i < yMSFT.length; i++) {yMSFT[i] = yMSFTp[i]}
        for (i = 0; i < yIBM.length; i++)  {yIBM[i] = yIBMp[i]}
    }
    source.trigger('change');
""")

shares = ['AAPL', 'MSFT', 'IBM', 'All']
multi_select = Select(title="Select Shares:", value=shares[3],     options=shares, callback=callback)
layout = VBox(multi_select, p)
show(layout)
```